# Groovy - Initializing String[] on the fly

Tags: arrays, groovy, initialization

### 1.Intro

I have a method that takes a `String[]` within a `Map`. I am generating this `map` within a unit test.

```
        Map<String, String[]> queryParameters = new HashMap<>();
        queryParameters.put("keywords",["keywords"].toArray()  )
        queryParameters.put("user", ["m"].toArray() )
        queryParameters.put("type", ["type"].toArray() )
```

Unfortunately `toArray()` produces an Array of Objects so it throws an exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;`

### 2.Current Solution

I would like to avoid having to initialize the String arrays as:

```
String[] keywords = ["keywords"];
queryParameters.put("keywords",keywords)
```

This works but it's annoying. Also I don't want to change the original Spring/Java method definition which is:

```
 public Page<LoggingEvent> findAll(Pageable pageable, Map<String, String[]> parameters) {
```

### 3.Question

What is the most concise way of entering `String Arrays` into a map??

I don't like `2. Current Solution`.

Comment: Groovy doesn't have casting? (I know nothing about Groovy other than that it's a language targeting the JVM.) If your current solution works, casting would presumably work...?

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder  Should have...  I did find this that works: `queryParameters.put("keywords",["keywords"].toArray(new String[1]));`

Comment: That's very much how you'd do it in Java, too, assuming Groovy treats `["keywords"]` as a `List`. Or if you don't know the length, `.toArray(new String[0])` which will cause `toArray` to allocate the array for you. But I'd think Groovy would have a better way, hope someone comes by with one. :-)

Comment: Is the question on groovy? Not sure why it is tagged to `java`. It works as it is, check [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5204967921025024) or [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=46813575161611288900)

Comment: Run in same situation with some legacy java code / groovy mix months ago and finally don't like all the casting stuff, it also didn't work in all cases. I changed the java method interfaces from arrays to lists - it needs some time but the result was clear code also in groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def parameters = [
        keywords: ["keywords"],
        users: ["m"],
        type: ["type"]
    ].collectEntries {[(it.key): it.value as String[]] } as HashMap<String, String[]>
```

Alternatively you could also do:

```
 def parameters = [
         keywords: ["keywords"] as String[],
         users: ["m"] as String[],
         type: ["type"] as String[]
     ]
```

Comment: it should be collectEntries, not collectEntires

Answer (score 2):

You can use metaprogramming in order to help your script :

```
Map.metaClass.asStringArrayMap = {
  delegate.collectEntries { key, value -> [(key): value as String[]] }
}

[keyword:'keywords', user:'m', type:'type'].asStringArrayMap()
```

Comment: Brilliant... so if all my tests extend from the same base class I can insert that metaclass definition there right?

Comment: overriding a metaclass is global : you don't need to extend a basescript, but you should add this new method before using it

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize array in inline as follow

```
Map<String, String[]> queryParameters = new HashMap<>();
queryParameters.put("keywords",new String[]{"keyword"});
queryParameters.put("user", new String[]{"m"});
queryParameters.put("type", new String[]{"type"});
```

Comment: unfortunately this fails in groovy :(